# How do I console.log JS variables as it relates to DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, visual-studio-code

Hi if I am working in VSCode and have declared a variable such as

```
const username = document.getElementById ("html-id")
```

and I try console.log(username) and run it in VSCode through code runner which is Node based I get a **document is not defined** error

How can I console.log and run my JS code to obtain the proper values?? I'm understanding it's through the browser but I'm not sure how to do that. Thanks!

Comment: `document` only exists in a browser. It refers to the HTML loaded by the browser and parsed into a DOM, but node doesn't process HTML, it only runs your JavaScript file. In that context, there is no document / DOM. Just open your HTML file in a browser, and if the script is properly referred in the document, it'll work fine.

Comment: You could aslo download a VSCode plugin to open in the browser the webpage you want to debug https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=Browser&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevanc This will open the raw HTML, you might want to run a development server to serve all of your source files imported by the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have here is that there is no DOM. Node is a runtime environment for JS to run outside the browser. DOM only exists in the browser.

To get the output you want:

1. Open the HTML file in browser.
2. Ctrl + Shift + I (if you are on Chrome ) to open the developer tools. Go to console Tab
3. Type `const username = document.getElementById ("html-id")` - enter
4. `console.log(username)` - You will get the desired output.

Comment: Thanks - if I have multiple JS + HTML + CSS files, how do I aggregate and deploy on a website? For example - I have a login page, and once it is logged in the page redirects to another page, but it doesn't load.

Comment: Try redirecting using js:  ` window.location.href = " Link you want to redirect to" `